# SqlDataReader is expecting a parameter that is not missing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am running into an issue where the error does not make sense. The immediate window says that the parameter is not missing but the debugger says that it is missing. No one at CP had an answer for this one.

> Error: Procedure or function 'cpWeeklyPharmDataintDrvr' expects parameter '@companyID', which was not supplied.

Immediate Window:

```
cmd.Parameters["@companyID"].Value 1356

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("cpWeeklyPharmDataintDrvr", sqlC);

sqlC.Open();

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@companyID", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Master.CompanyId;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sStartDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30)).Value = Master.StartDate;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sEndDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30)).Value = Master.EndDate;

if (Master.RegionId > 0)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@region", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Master.RegionId;

if (Master.DistrictId > 0)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@district", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = Master.DistrictId;

if (Master.StoreId . 0)
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@store", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = Master.StoreId.ToString();

SqlDataReader dR = cmd.ExecuteReader();    // This is where error occurs.
```

Comment: You add the parameter to the collection only if Master.CompanyID is Greater than zero. But the SP doesn't like this optionality. This parameter should always be specified.

Comment: Code modified, this is still getting the same error. The immediate window reports that the value is indeed, not missing.

Comment: are any of the prior parameters being skipped? also are you specifying your command is a stored proc?

Comment: Going to have to give us the sql then

Comment: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` THIS IS IMPORTANT

Comment: Like @lincolnk said, try setting your `cmd.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.  It defaults to `Text`.

Comment: Could you add the declaration of the Stored Procedure in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

I can observe two things

1. Type of CommandType , set it to `StoredProcedures`
2. Null value in company id.

Try passing some hardcoded value and see if works. Sometime in null it says the same. And in your sp declare your parameter as `@companyId int =null`, so that it can accept null values too.

Answer (score 0):

You have the add parameter statements inside of if statements.  If the if fails, you don't do anything but the procedure will fail.  Add an else statement that throws an error or sets the parameter to a default value if it is not there.

Also check to see if Master.CompanyId is null.  That could cause an error.  Finally, the Add method may not work correctly.

Try AddWithValue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try running a SQL profiler to see what is the parameter getting pass to the stored procedure? you can see if those parameters looks correct to you together with the logic you have in database. (which you didn't post in the question)

Also, you need to specify the commandtype as StoredProcedure as well.

Comment: I have a temporary solution right now where I am using a stringbuilder to build my SQL command, it is workign for the moment but I'd rather use this style. I will definitely use Steve's suggestion as well.

I use Visual Studio, Intellitrace will tell me what Stored Procedure was run but does not say what parameters are being passed.

I don't think I have any experience actually using a SQL profiler.

Comment: Thank you, setting cmd as Stored Procedure fixed it.